# write text to pdf with itextsharp in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, vb.net-2010

I have a sub in vb.net like:

```
Public Shared f_cb As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\plantillas\fonts\trebucbd.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
    Public Shared f_cn As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\plantillas\fonts\trebuc.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)


Public Shared Sub GenPDF()
Try
   Using fs As System.IO.FileStream = New FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\te\TEST.pdf", FileMode.Create)
                Dim document As New Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 1)
                Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs)
                document.AddTitle("test")
                document.Open()
                Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
                Dim png As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Current.Server.MapPath("Images/logo.jpg"))
                png.ScaleAbsolute(75, 52)
                png.SetAbsolutePosition(40, 770)
                cb.AddImage(png)
                cb.BeginText()

                Dim left_margin As Integer = 40
                Dim top_margin As Integer = 750
                write(cb, "Streets S.R.L.", left_margin, top_margin, f_cb, 10)
                write(cb, "Av. 900, C.A.B.A. (1001), Peru", left_margin, top_margin - 12, f_cn, 8)
                write(cb, "Tel: 4300-2147 - Fax: 4300-2148", left_margin, top_margin - 24, f_cn, 8)
                write(cb, "C.U.I.T. 20-30602227-0", left_margin, top_margin - 36, f_cn, 10)
                write(cb, "I.V.A.", left_margin, top_margin - 48, f_cn, 10)
                cb.EndText()
                document.Close()
                writer.Close()
                fs.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

Public Shared Sub write(ByVal cb As PdfContentByte, ByVal Text As String, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal font As BaseFont, ByVal Size As Integer)
        cb.SetFontAndSize(font, Size)
        cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, Text, X, Y, 0)
    End Sub
```

So it works ok, now I would like to write to an already created pdf, but I can not find analog for vb.net I was trying pdfStamper but had no succes, How does the code to append data to pdf using itextsharp in vb.net look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of writing text to an existing PDF file and then saving it with a new name:

```vb
Dim oldFile As String = "SomePath/Existing.pdf"
Dim newFile As String = "SomePath/New.pdf"

' Create reader
Dim reader As New PdfReader(oldFile)
Dim size As Rectangle = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)
Dim document As New Document(size)

' Create the writer
Dim fs As New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs)
document.Open()
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

' Set the font, color and size properties for writing text to the PDF
Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY)
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8)

' Write text in the PDF
cb.BeginText()
Dim text As String = "Some text here"

' Set the alignment and coordinates here
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0)
cb.EndText()

' Put the text on a new page in the PDF 
Dim page As PdfImportedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1)
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0)

' Close the objects
document.Close()
fs.Close()
writer.Close()
reader.Close()
```

Comment: @cMinor While doing it like this certainly is *a* solution, it is not necessarily *the best* one. Adding templates generated by `PdfWriter.GetImportedPage` makes you a) lose all page annotations (e.g. form elements) and b) wraps the whole page in a xobject. Whether either is a show stopper, depends on the requirements and use case. Generally a better approach is to use a `PdfStamper` which can also add page content by means of its `OverContent` and `UnderContent`.

Answer (score 0):

While this question's original answer was very helpful, it doesn't work anymore due to natural evolution of the PdfSharp library. With the *PdfWriter* class now being *friend* (=inaccessible), it seems the authors want to promote using of the high-level functions of *document* instead.

For those who used the above approach and it didn't work - if you just need to edit the pdf, and it's enough to do it graphically (*no search, etc.*), this is how (*vb.net*):

```
Public Sub AppendText(SourcePath As String, TargetPath As String,
                           Text As String, someFont As Font,
                           left As Single, top As Single)
  Dim document As PdfDocument = IO.PdfReader.Open(SourcePath)
  Dim Page As PdfPage = document.Pages.Item(0)
  Dim GFX As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(Page)
  Dim someXFont As New XFont(someFont.FontFamily.Name, someFont.Size)
  GFX.DrawString(Text, someXFont, XBrushes.Red, New PointF(left, top))
  document.Save(TargetPath)
End Sub
```

I'm still running into issues regarding the positioning, but the code is otherwise running (12/2019)